# Magento customer login hangs on some accounts

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have been looking everywhere for an answer but can't find anything that helps.

I have a magento 1.7.2 install, and some customers can't login into their account area, the website just hangs. They don't get no error or anything.  It was that bad that it brought down a whole server when multiple customers were logging in at the same time.

I have since moved on to a new server an it still happens, but doesn't crash the server.
The only way I can get round the issue is resetting the customer password in the admin - but i need to know what is causing it.

Note, this is standard Magento 1.7.2 login system - no customer modules etc. It only happens on some customers too, as many can log in fine.

Comment: have you checked the php error log (location can be found in php.ini, magento's error log ({{base_dir}}/var/log/), and your webserver error log? any clues there?

Comment: Anything specific about their usernames? Odd chars?

Comment: Hi. Yes I checked the error logs and it said MySQL server has gone away and Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=8345. This was on the old server.

Comment: No, characters were fine - no dodgy ones

Comment: New server, I'm getting a lot of exceptions 'Zend_Date_Exception' with message 'Unable to parse date '27/121992' using 'dd/MM/yyyy' (M <> d)' in /app/code/core/Zend/Date.php:2675

Comment: I am getting this query logged as slow querys - Fri Jul 19 03:09:55 2013
# Query_time: 2.219437  Lock_time: 0.000538 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1374224995;
INSERT INTO `log_visitor` (`session_id`, `first_visit_at`, `last_visit_at`, `last_url_id`, `store_id`) VALUES ('176611a751e06ce92acee1d27b32e120', '2013-07-19 09:09:53', '2013-07-19 09:09:53', '0', '1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it appeared that my cron wasn't triggering the log cleaner in magento. There were stupid amount of data in tables such as log_visitor, log_visitor_url.  I believe this was slowing down the performance of my magento site causing the login to hang in some cases.

I followed this tutorial to TRUNCATE various tables - and I have noticed a difference at login.

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/magneto-log-and-cache-maintenance-script/

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Comment: Issue still persist

Answer (score 0):

it might be something related to cart, try this fix:

UPDATE quote set is_active = 1 where is_active = 0;